# Depoly wso2 API_M 3.2.0 on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, wso2

I need to deploy wso2 APIM 3.2.0 on kubernetes, by myself I didn't find any documentation. Can anybody consider any tips or reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the WSO2 Kubernetes artifacts in [this](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/tree/3.2.x) Github repository. Note the branch `3.2.x`. Artifacts relevant to APIM 3.2.0 is located in this branch. Within this branch, you have helm charts for different deployment patterns. For example something like [this](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/tree/3.2.x/advanced/am-pattern-1).